# Interpolation and derivative on Java

Tags: java, numerical-methods, apache-commons-math

I am trying to make a project witch involves calculating an interpolation from raw data and its derivative.
I have two arrays looking like this:

```
A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , n }
B = { 0.23, 0.43, 0.24, 0.19, ... , n }
```

I want a function to describe the following arrays, so I am using apache-common-math library in order to interpolate the polynom that will describe a function where: F(A[i]) = B[i].
Afterwards, I wish to calculate the derivative of this function in order to be able to find extremum(max/min).

For some reason, I am having trouble with the derivative part.

Currently using:

```
        DividedDifferenceInterpolator devider = new DividedDifferenceInterpolator();
        PolynomialFunctionNewtonForm polynom = devider.interpolate(xArray,  
        yArray);
```

Now i have polynom, which is the function representing my previous arrays.
How should I calculate its derivative..?

Thanks.

Comment: The interpolating polynomial function constructed using `N` points can potentially have `N-2` extrema. So are you interested in calculating all these extrema? Secondly, its better to use a optimization library instead of interpolating, differentiating and then finding the root.You may try the common maths optimization library to calculate extrema instead. The documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
yes, i wish to find all of them or several in a certain region.
I have tried working the the optimization library, and having trouble there as well. for some reason the derivative is a problem because i do not fully understand how should i calculate derivative for a newtonForm function from the explanation provided by apache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the derivative by extracting the coefficients from the Newton form polynomial, creating a `PolynomialFunction` from it and then using that function's `derivative` method. Here is an example:

```
double[] x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
double[] y = new double[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    y[i] = 1 + 2 * x[i] + 3 * x[i] * x[i];
}
DividedDifferenceInterpolator divider = new DividedDifferenceInterpolator();
PolynomialFunctionNewtonForm polynom = divider.interpolate(x, y);
double[] coefficients = polynom.getCoefficients();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coefficients));
PolynomialFunction derivative =
 (PolynomialFunction) new PolynomialFunction(coefficients).derivative();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(derivative.getCoefficients()));
```

The code above generates points from the polynomial y = 1 + 2x + 3x^2.  The output should be

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[2.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the derivative of the polynomial much easily by using Lagrange polynomial instead of using a library.

You may write a simple function (implement `UnivariateFunction` from apache Commons). Refer to the equation by @Krokop on [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809927/first-derivative-of-lagrange-polynomial).

Then you may use the root-finding library from commons math [given here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.3_Root-finding), look at the "typical usage" given on the page.

I am not sure if there is a much simpler way of doing it.